# How to remove the error of the \ begin {cases} command bound with the \ begin {enumerate} command?

Tags: environments

I'm trying to write this:

```
\begin{nscenter}
        % $G(\psi,\chi) = 
        \
        % \begin{cases}
        % \begin{enumerate}[\rm(i)]
        % \item q-1 \ se \ \psi=\psi_0 \ e \ \chi=\chi_0 \\
        % \item -1 \ se \ \psi=\psi_0 \ e \ \chi \neq \chi_0 \\
         % \item 0 \ se \psi \neq \psi_0 \ e \ \chi=\chi_0 \\
         $ \item Se \ \chi \neq \chi_0 \ e \ \psi \neq \psi_0 \Rightarrow  $ |G(\psi,\chi)|=\sqrt{q}
         $ \end{enumerate}

        $ \end{cases}$ 
    %\end{nscenter}
```

But the compiler of the error and I do not know what to do to remove the error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. (you have to leave an empty line before pressing the `{}` for placing your code in its environment). But please make your code "semi-compilable". I mean, it is ok to reproduce the error you have, but it is not ok to miss a `\begin{document}` or a needed package... or documentclass etc.

Comment: Where is the error?

Comment: @Maik: So you want to enumerate the items within a `cases` environment? What does `nscenter` do?

Comment: The error seems to be in the`` \\end{nscenter}` which is commented, whereas `\begin{nscenter]` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be advised to enumerate the items within a `cases` environment presented in your way manually. That is, insert `(i)`, `(ii)`, `(iii)` and `(iv)` on the respective rows as needed.

Below I used [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) to align the enumeration to the `r`ight, although you can change this to suit your needs (requires two compilations on the first go).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,cases,eqparbox}

\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{cases}
    \eqmakebox[casecnt][r]{  (i)}\ q - 1 & \text{se $\psi = \psi_0$ e $\chi = \chi_0$}    \\
    \eqmakebox[casecnt][r]{ (ii)}\ -1    & \text{se $\psi = \psi_0$ e $\chi \neq \chi_0$} \\
    \eqmakebox[casecnt][r]{(iii)}\ 0     & \text{se $\psi \neq \psi_0$ e $\chi = \chi_0$} \\
    \eqmakebox[casecnt][r]{ (iv)}        & \text{Se $\chi \neq \chi_0$ e 
                                                  $\psi \neq \psi_0 \Rightarrow \lvert G(\psi,\chi)\rvert = \sqrt{q}$}
  \end{cases}
\]

\begin{subequations}
\begin{numcases}{}
  q - 1 & \text{se $\psi = \psi_0$ e $\chi = \chi_0$}    \\
  -1    & \text{se $\psi = \psi_0$ e $\chi \neq \chi_0$} \\
  0     & \text{se $\psi \neq \psi_0$ e $\chi = \chi_0$} \\
        & \text{Se $\chi \neq \chi_0$ e 
                  $\psi \neq \psi_0 \Rightarrow \lvert G(\psi,\chi)\rvert = \sqrt{q}$}
\end{numcases}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I also provide an alternative that is far more intuitive using [`numcases`](//ctan.org/pkg/numcases). Rather number each equation in the usual way, perhaps with a `subequations` formatting. This allows you to `\label`-`\ref` the elements as expected.